# Connecting GWT application with database in Intellij

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea, gwt

I am switching to Intellij from Netbeans on  a gwt project 
I want to know how to connect My application to the database (Mysql) in netbeans it was easy to do , but in intellij i don't know how ..
Does anyone know how . and can you show how to do it ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-database-tool-window.html ? This only appears in the Ultimate edition. I don't think this question has much to do with GWT - you may consider removing the tag.

Comment: sorry for not answering my question until now , i was a little busy , I think you"re right this has to do with Intellij and JPA but it's part of gwt project , i tagged this question with GWT because almost all gwt developper may have worked with JPA i wanted to get gwt developper attention ,

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you need to add a datasource from

> View -> Tool Windows -> Database

after configuring the datasource according to your database , you need to assign it to your JPA persistence.xml 
left click on the persistence file in JPA configuration browser not in the project file tree , 
and click "Assign Datasource" and chose the datasource you created before 
Thanks everyone